# How to set nginx ingress with command helm create?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

I can't make my ingress work in local `docker-desktop`

I made an `helm create my-project-helm` like everybody

then I do changes in `./my-project-helm/values.yaml` I just show you the most interesting part (about ingress)

```
...

replicaCount: 3

image:
  repository: localhost:5000/my-project-helm
  tag: latest
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

...

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80

ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: {
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  }
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: [/]

...
```

I install this helm `helm upgrade --install my-project-helm ./my-project-helm`

I install nginx `helm upgrade --install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress`

I am gonna check my ingress with `kubectl describe ingress my-project-helm`

```
Name:             my-project-helm
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                 Path  Backends
  ----                 ----  --------
  chart-example.local  /     my-project-helm:80 (10.1.0.71:80,10.1.0.72:80,10.1.0.73:80)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  nginx
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  14m   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/my-project-helm
  Normal  UPDATE  13m   nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/my-project-helm
```

Everything seems so wonderful.

I make a `curl chart-example.local` nothing happens `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: chart-example.local`

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Did you try to access directly using the [docker-machine IP address](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#run-containers-and-experiment-with-machine-commands)? (`docker-machine ip default`). You need to add `chart-example.local` to your `/etc/hosts` to make it resolve to the virtual machine address.

Comment: I have no docker-machine ! But I am willing to set a dnsmasq. I wanna know which IP I need to use to resole the end of domain .local ???

Comment: Thanks I just added an update in my original post.

Comment: Please, do not post the solution on the question. The proper way to do this is to [answer and accept your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/353042).

Comment: Cheers mate you rock !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it should add the `Kubernetes master` domain in your /etc/hosts

Check it with `kubectl cluster-info`

So just use the default domain which is in my case `kubernetes.docker.internal` instead of `chart-example.local`.

And yes it must point to the loadbalancer external IP of nginx which is localhost by default ;)